# How to comment code java/c#

Tags: c#, java, comments

say if I have the code

```
  static private String[][] getRssData(String channel)
 {
     //Code here...
 }
```

Is there a way i can view a description of the function on hover-over?
ie adding

```
 //this is Using to get the RssData
```

I intend to do this with both c# and java coding

Comment: You mean Javadoc ? see also: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Comment: Can't you do this just by adding comments/JavaDoc to your function(s)?

Comment: I think he wants a tooltip-type little popup that he can look at as he's coding.  Javadocs are for post-compilation only, and are more of a global reference rather than a localized "what does this do again?" thing.  If this is the case, I can't help.  If not, Javadocs are def. the way to go.

Comment: @RussellUhl a modern IDE can show javadoc immediately.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen well that's just spiffy.  Clearly, I haven't been paying attention.

Answer (score 6):

In the Visual Studio IDE for C#, you can use the [XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
///<summary>
///This is used to get the RSS data
///</summary>
///<param name="channel">The channel</param>
///<returns>The RSS data</returns>
private static string[][] GetRssData(string channel)
{
    //...
}
```

You can use with [Javadoc] plugin in Android Studio(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) to do the same in Java:

```
/**
* This is used to get the RSS data 
* @param channel The channel
* @return The RSS data
*/
static String[][] getRssData(String channel)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In c# type `///` above the method and sumarry stub will automatically be generated

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can do it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// this is Using to get the RssData
/// </summary>
static private string[][] GetRssData(string channel)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

[More about `<summary>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In Java:

```
/**
* this is Using to get the RssData
*/
static private string[][] getRssData(String channel)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

Comment: anyway to do this with java?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, Javadoc comments are the preferred way to write documenting comments.

Just put

```
/**
 * Your comments go here.
 */
```

Before the method header, and your IDE can probably display the comment formatted in html.

Also, you can use the javadoc tool to generate html documentation for your code, exactly like the API's.

Here's a guide for writing good javadoc comments: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way i can view a description of the function on hover-over?

That is a function of the IDE you are using, not the language.  If you look at your source code in (say) Notepad, there's no way you will get hover-text.

But (for example) the Eclipse IDE can format and display a method's javadoc comments in a popup window when you hover over the method name in the source code.  (You don't need to post-process the javadoc to HTML for this to happen.  Eclipse extracts the relevant comment from the source code on the fly.)

Comment: I am amazed how the other answers seemed to neglect this fact.